# Indexed search and site management's slug cause issue with custom TYPO3 extensions

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x, tx-indexed-search

**TYPO3 Environment**

- TYPO3 v9.5.3
- EXT:news (7.0.8)
- EXT:indexed_search (9.5.3)
- Use Composer: No

**The Problem**

- On EXT:indexed_search result listing page, Custom extension record's slug URL are not generating. The slug only contains TYPO3 page URL.
- Example; The URL should be http://thedomain.com/news/detail/announce-first-news/, but it currently only generates http://thedomain.com/news/

As per our analysis, it seems TYPO3 v9 site management's slug feature cause issue, and there could be following possible issues.

**Issue #1**

The major issue is, After enabling site management's slug setup, No more indexing happening for a custom extension.

**Issue #2**

Indexing result will lose after the page will refresh or move to another page (After clear cache data will show again).

**Issue #3**

If we create new records for a custom extension, then the created new records will not be indexing.

**Issue #4**

If anyhow, we have done the indexing and search works well, then at search result listing page, The link redirect to the main action like Listing. Because cHash is missing to each record, That's a bit strange!

Does anyone have any idea/solution? Highly appreciate your any thoughts, Thanks a lot!

Cheers,

Team NITSAN

Comment: Please update always to the latest version to go sure, that the problem still exists and wasn't fixed already.

Comment: Hey @sven-wappler, You are correct! After Upgrade to TYPO3 v9.5.5, all the issues are resolved. For such core-level issue, we will always take care to upgrade to the latest one. Thanks for your feedback and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed with release of 9.5.5, released 4.3.2019. Check out the release notes which you can find here: https://get.typo3.org/release-notes/9.5.5

The issue for the bug is https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86994

---

However there has been also a regression detected which is described at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87855 but it has already been fixed as well. The bug occurs if MYSQL strict mode is used

Comment: Only Issue 1-3 is fixed with 9.5.5

Comment: Hey @georg-ringer Perfect, After upgrading to TYPO3 **v9.5.5** everything works well. Thanks a lot for your so quick response. We highly admire **your great dedicated efforts** to the TYPO3 community :)

Comment: Hey @AlexanderGrein All 1-4 issues are resolved, we have well-tested with TYPO3 v9.5.5, everything seems works well. Let us know if we can help you.